# catalog search not giving exact result magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, magento-community, magento2.3.0

In magento 2.3.2 community edition, the catalog search not giving exact result. I have set Minimal Query Length =>2, I searched "wine cooler" but I getting result list karoo angel products. If I search same in this in admin panel it gives me exact result of wine glasses.
I have set proirity in store>attribute name to 1 and short description and description set no. still issue of result somehow chaged.

[image]

Please see this in attached image.

Answer (score 0):

Try with turn off option of searchable attribute of Description and Short Description.

> Go to Stores > Attributes > Product > Search Description and Short Description Then
>
> Choose Storefront Properties > **Use in Search > NO**

Use in search option set to NO. Then Run Command and Check this will work properly.

Comment: i have tried this but it also give me same result.

Comment: Then There is some problem in your search, Try to use any module for search.

Comment: if I search other products it gives me exact result. Only issue is for this product.If search wine then angel type products it shows in list

Comment: this error comes when you search 2 words, for one word it will work properly

Comment: no. I am searching just "wine" that time also same result. And i have set short description and description set no, and product name to weitage to 1.

Comment: Then you need to debug the code or product info.

Comment: I have tried with mageplaza extention to disable. If i want to see in code then which module i have to check. I search navigation and catlog search module but related filter code is not seen.

Comment: Check the Models of Magento Catalog Search Module, also try with Query which have missing %%LIKE%% Parameter.

Comment: this perticuler products have any attribute which you can add elastic search yes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same trouble - if I search for 'square plate' it will show lots of products that might have the word plate somewhere in it, but only choose to show the product actually called square plate half way down the results page.
Clicking the relevancy arrow up/down doesn't change the order of the results either.